# Is there any difference between private, public, package keywords during runtime?

Tags: java, scope

I know that the Java have these serval keywords to identify the variable scope during development, but I would like to know whether this is different when it is in a production environment or just for coder interest? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accessibility is enforced at runtime as well. If some code tries to access a member that it shouldn't, then `IllegalAccessException` or `IllegalAccessError` is thrown. Here's a quick demonstration:

```
public class AccessTest {
    public int publicNumber;
    private int secretNumber;
}

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        reflection();
        noReflection();
    }

    private static void noReflection() throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
        int a = new AccessTest().publicNumber;
          //                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
          // To be changed to secretNumber in bytecode editor after compilation

        System.out.println("Number read: " + a);
    }

    private static void reflection() throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
        AccessTest instance = new AccessTest();
        AccessTest.class.getDeclaredField("publicNumber").get(instance); // <-- Works
        try {
            AccessTest.class.getDeclaredField("secretNumber").get(instance); // <-- Throws IllegalAccessException
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            System.out.println("Caught IllegalAccessException");
        }
    }
}
```

### With reflection:

As it is, the above program outputs:

```
Caught IllegalAccessException
Number read: 10
```

### Without reflection:

When I use a bytecode editor to change

```
getfield com/blah/access/AccessTest/publicNumber I
```

in method `noReflection()` to:

```
getfield com/blah/access/AccessTest/secretNumber I
```

the output is:

```
Caught IllegalAccessException
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field com.blah.access.AccessTest.secretNumber from class com.blah.access.Client
at com.blah.access.Client.noReflection(Client.java)
at com.blah.access.Client.main(Client.java:12)
```

As Michael mentioned this behavior may be JVM dependent. I ran this on

```
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I wonder if these exception also get thrown when not using reflection (but a maliciously compiled class). My guess is that you'd get some kind of Error, too.

Comment: @Thilo: I think it should be caught by bytecode verification. Though there are embedded JVMs which skip that step.

Comment: @thilo: Interesting point! Updated with findings on the no-reflection case.

Answer (score 5):

No, the JVM actually checks and enforces visibility at runtime.

There are ways to get around that using reflection, but a SecurityManager can forbid that, too.

Answer (score 2):

The checks are done at runtime, as well as compile time. There are a whole load of exceptions of this type which can be thrown at runtime, for example [IllegalAccessException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalAccessException.html):

> An IllegalAccessException is thrown when an application tries to
>   reflectively create an instance (other than an array), set or get a
>   field, or invoke a method, but the currently executing method does not
>   have access to the definition of the specified class, field, method or
>   constructor.

Comment: I wonder if these exception also get thrown when not using reflection (but a maliciously compiled class). My guess is that you'd get some kind of Error, too.

Comment: Yes, you would get this sort of error with a maliciously (or erroneously) compiled class.

Comment: @Thilo - You would get an `Error` rather than a `Exception` when not using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

The checks are performed at runtime (as well as compile time) However, these checks, while relatively expensive are usually performed once per call, and don't make much difference.

Two exceptions I can think of are;

- If you access a private member of a class in the same file, an accessor method needs to be created (as the JVM doesn't allow access to private member from another class, nested or otherwise)  This doesn't impact performance as much as you might think as the method can be inlined.  What it can do is add a confusing `access$100` method into your call stack
- If you use reflection, the check appears to be performed every time.  If you use `member.setAccessible(true)` it disables the security check and can make the access/invocation faster even if the member is public.